# in GCP functions local simulator is there a way to only load certain functions?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I have an app with dozens of functions and it takes a long time to reload.
Is there a way to make it only load certain functions at startup?

I tried the same syntax as deploying only some funcs like:

```
npm run build:watch | firebase emulators:start --only functions:v2-icons-assets,functions:v2-icons-jokers
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator

also a way to suppress the pages of `functions: Loaded functions definitions from source: ....` would be nice. It completely covers any informative logging I had.

Comment: If you have exported all the functions then all the functions will load at startup.Hence you can't really dynamically load any particular at startup. Also exporting a function and saving the file to make this function load after emulator startup does not work either.

Comment: ok i guess I can add my own conditional imports based on some ENV var then.